# Problem with encoding when reading text from a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to read different file in different languages and then change same text in this file and save result (for example, shift the letters as in Caesar's cipher). Now I read file so as below, but it work normal only with English language. If I try to read file with another language characters are not displayed correctly. I try to use `setlocale()` but it didn't give any results. I'd like to know is there any general way of reading such files?
I do it in Visual Studio and use Unicode in properties.

```
ifstream full_file("test.txt");
if (full_file.is_open()) {
    char ch;
    while (full_file >> ch) {   
        /* ... */
    }
    full_file.close();
}
```

Comment: try using `wchar_t` instead of `char`

Comment: It depends on what format the file is using. It could be Windows old ANSI format, UTF8 or UTF16. Open the file with Notepad, try to save it, it will say the format at the bottom. Caesar's cipher is for A to Z, it has to be adjusted depending on the format.

Comment: Just another iostream liability, the C++ standard has given up on it by deprecating std::codecvt.  The Microsoft CRT allows fopen() to specify the encoding with "ccs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change ANSI format instead UTF8 format in *.txt file and it helped solve the problem, thanks.